# Nokogiri - Selecting a link between two &quot s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nokogiri

I'm having trouble selecting a link that's part of an embeded code. It's between two `&quot`s. I've put a link to the code that I'm trying with.

Thank you.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d2efee7b3967debc531d67de9cc7993a/raw/3f5e0e63ce6fe3aa4cffc2d0afafd2415408308a/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". The minimal code that demonstrates the problem needs to be _in the question itself_, along with the minimum input data and the expected output. Links rot then break and when they do the question will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct Form is.

```
(?<=&quot;)(.*)(?=&quot;)
```

Input:

```
&quot;https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d2efee7b3967debc531d67de9cc7993a/raw/3f5e0e63ce6fe3aa4cffc2d0afafd2415408308a/gistfile1.txt&quot;
```

Output:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d2efee7b3967debc531d67de9cc7993a/raw/3f5e0e63ce6fe3aa4cffc2d0afafd2415408308a/gistfile1.txt
```

Ruby Code:

```
re = /(?<=&quot;)(.*)(?=&quot;)/m
str = '&quot;https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d2efee7b3967debc531d67de9cc7993a/raw/3f5e0e63ce6fe3aa4cffc2d0afafd2415408308a/gistfile1.txt&quot;'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Test Code: http://ideone.com/moljMo

See: https://regex101.com/r/vrBUhc/1